# Conditional format rule referencing another Sheet, when copying over existing conditional format rulesets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have existing conditional format rules, in the first Sheet that I created, which is already being used. However, I want it such that, when a new Sheet is created, those rules copy over to the new Sheet as well.

Thus far, I have done the following:

**Code**

```
/**
 *  Automatically applies conditional formatting to all the Sheets, based on that of the first one
 **/
function autoConditionalFormat() {
  // get all the sheets
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();


  // get the first spreadsheet
  const firstSheet = sheets[0],
      conditionalFormatRules = firstSheet.getConditionalFormatRules();

  sheets.forEach(function(sheet, idx) { 
                 if (idx) { 
                   // for some reason, this is throwing an Error: Conditional format rule cannot reference a different sheet. at [unknown function](Code:16) at autoConditionalFormat(Code:14)
                   sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
                 }
  })

}
```

**Result**

When I create a trigger to, on change, run this code, the following error occurs:

```
Conditional format rule cannot reference a different sheet. (line 17, file "Code")
```

Is there a way to do this without hard-coding the conditional format rules or manually creating a full template Sheet that the listener function simply pastes to the new Sheet?

Comment: What's the formula used?

Comment: There is no "formula" used. I told you: I manually created the conditional **format** rules! (`Format > Conditional Formatting...`)

Comment: So, what's the rule?

Comment: There's multiple rules, per column, on three columns; /* am I going to have to hard-code them?! */

Comment: I'm not hearing necessary info about the rules. But you can easily use copy paste format: Something like get all range in sheet1> `.copyTo(Sheet2.getRange(..),{formatOnly:true})`